# Дебаг dll с помощью IDA PRO 7.0

Tags: ассемблер, dll, reverse-engineering, ida-pro

Пишу веб-сервер на .Net который будет работать со сканером отпечатков пальцев ZKTeco. Столкнулся с проблемой авторизации со сканером при наличии установленного пароля на нем. Так, как официальный сапорт не хочет дать ответ, как проводится расчет 4байтного ответа, ссылаясь, что это source code, но мне нужно сам алгоритм. Я решил запустить на дебаг официальное SDK. Возникают проблемы с запуском отдельной dll, нужно передать параметры, но я не могу разобратса как узнать что именно туда приходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если программа написана на .Net, то возьмите JetBrains dotPeek. Он вам декомпилирует ее и создаст готовый проект, в котором можно сделать изменения и собрать его назад.